# Getting 'invalid reference format' error on localstack when use 'aws lambda invoke'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, localstack

I'm using localstack/terraform/aws (latest versions) to play with lambda on aws locally. The configuration can be found here https://github.com/wentao-daommo/aws-local

While I can successfully setup/deploy everything and list my lambda function via 'aws lambda list-functions'. I was unable to invoke the function with command

```bash
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name=handler --payload='' test.json
```

From the command line, I got error

```html
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "LogResult": "",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

and from localstack, I saw this error message, which I don't understand at all

```html
localstack_1  | ERROR: 'docker create --rm --name "localstack_lambda_arn_aws_lambda_us-east-1_000000000000_function_handler" --entrypoint /bin/bash  --interactive -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY="$AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY" -e HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="$LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME" -e EDGE_PORT="$EDGE_PORT"  -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY='{}' -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=192.168.65.2 -e EDGE_PORT=4566 -e _HANDLER=exports.handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT=3 -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME=handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION='$LATEST' -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN=arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_COGNITO_IDENTITY='{}' -e _LAMBDA_SERVER_PORT=5002     "lambci/lambda:"': exit code 1; output: b'invalid reference format\n'
localstack_1  | 2021-01-26T04:08:07:INFO:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Error executing Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handler: Command 'docker create --rm --name "localstack_lambda_arn_aws_lambda_us-east-1_000000000000_function_handler" --entrypoint /bin/bash  --interactive -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY="$AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY" -e HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="$LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME" -e EDGE_PORT="$EDGE_PORT"  -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY='{}' -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=192.168.65.2 -e EDGE_PORT=4566 -e _HANDLER=exports.handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT=3 -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME=handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION='$LATEST' -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN=arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_COGNITO_IDENTITY='{}' -e _LAMBDA_SERVER_PORT=5002     "lambci/lambda:"' returned non-zero exit status 1. Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_api.py", line 550, in run_lambda
localstack_1  |     result = LAMBDA_EXECUTOR.execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context=context,
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 178, in execute
localstack_1  |     return do_execute()
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 170, in do_execute
localstack_1  |     return _run(func_arn=func_arn)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 149, in wrapped
localstack_1  |     raise e
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 145, in wrapped
localstack_1  |     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 161, in _run
localstack_1  |     raise e
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 149, in _run
localstack_1  |     result = self._execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context, version)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 399, in _execute
localstack_1  |     return super(LambdaExecutorReuseContainers, self)._execute(func_arn, *args, **kwargs)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 323, in _execute
localstack_1  |     cmd = self.prepare_execution(func_details, environment, command)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 366, in prepare_execution
localstack_1  |     container_info = self.prime_docker_container(func_details, env_vars.items(), lambda_cwd)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 474, in prime_docker_container
localstack_1  |     run(cmd)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/common.py", line 1312, in run
localstack_1  |     return do_run(cmd)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/common.py", line 1309, in do_run
localstack_1  |     return bootstrap.run(cmd, **kwargs)
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/bootstrap.py", line 656, in run
localstack_1  |     raise e
localstack_1  |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/bootstrap.py", line 616, in run
localstack_1  |     output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=stderr, env=env_dict, cwd=cwd)
localstack_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
localstack_1  |     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
localstack_1  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
localstack_1  |     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
localstack_1  | subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'docker create --rm --name "localstack_lambda_arn_aws_lambda_us-east-1_000000000000_function_handler" --entrypoint /bin/bash  --interactive -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY="$AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY" -e HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="$LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME" -e EDGE_PORT="$EDGE_PORT"  -e AWS_LAMBDA_EVENT_BODY='{}' -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME=192.168.65.2 -e EDGE_PORT=4566 -e _HANDLER=exports.handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT=3 -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME=handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION='$LATEST' -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN=arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:handler -e AWS_LAMBDA_COGNITO_IDENTITY='{}' -e _LAMBDA_SERVER_PORT=5002     "lambci/lambda:"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please confirm that this is version 0.12.5 or again old 0.10.5?

Comment: It is the 0.12.5 version, as I'm using port 4566 everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **handler is incorrect** and you are **missing runtime**. I would also recommend using standard `main.js` in the form of:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify("Hi from lambda on localstack")
    }
};
```

Then, your `aws_lambda_function` with correct `handler` and `runtime` should be:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  filename      = "lambda_file.zip"
  function_name = "handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x"
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler       = "main.handler"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.archive_file.lambda_file.output_path)
}
```